# Will Windows 8 preview stop working and required a different license in the future?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8-preview, license

I'm planning on installing [Windows 8 preview](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/consumer-preview) on a spare laptop.  I looked all over the faq page but did not see anything about how the licensing works.  I understand that it's free for me to install right now.

My question is once Windows 8 is released, will my current license still work or will the preview version essentially stop working?  Will the preview version be allowed upgrades/fixes (I figure this is less likely).  Essentially I'm wondering if early adopters/testers will be allowed to keep their license in exchange for trying out the new OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Developer Preview was set to expire March 12, 2012, but it along with the Consumer Preview expires Jan 15, 2013. http://makingwindowseasy.com/2012/02/18/microsoft-changes-windows-8-dev-preview-expiration-date/

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several things, including signs at retail stores, that said the upgrade from Windows 7 to 8 would cost $14.99. I think that is fair and much less than any other Windows upgrade has been.

I am using Windows 8 right now (Samsung slate tablet PC) with the touch-screen keyboard, and I like it.